# Javascript `Path2D` arc isn't rendering

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I wrote the following script

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("crystal").getContext('2d');
var frontback = new Path2D("M 10 10 h 100 v 100 h -100 Z");
var leftright = new Path2D("M 10 10 l 20 20 v 100 l -20 -20");

ctx.save();

ctx.stroke(frontback);
ctx.stroke(leftright);

ctx.translate(20,20);
ctx.stroke(frontback);
ctx.restore();

ctx.translate(100,0);
ctx.stroke(leftright);
ctx.restore();

var pos_ion = new Path2D("M 55 55 A 10 10 0 0 1 55 55");
ctx.stroke(pos_ion);
```

The lines show as desired but the circle doesn't show at all.  As I understand the inputs after "A", it should be saying that the horizontal and vertical radii are 10, the start angle is `0`, the large-arc-flag I tried reading up on but don't fully understand.  But the choice of sweep shouldn't matter, I think.  And the center is at `(55,55)`.  Sounds to me like it should work but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what happens in your `var pos_ion = new Path2D("M 55 55 A 10 10 0 0 1 55 55");` line of code. You move your `stroke` to `(55,55)` coordinates and then you're trying to draw your arc using below parameters.

`rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x  y`

`10 10 0               0              1          55 55`

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths):

> The final two parameters designate the x and y coordinates to end the stroke

So the problem is that the beginning and the end of your stroke are exactly the same point `(55,55)`. You can try to modify those params a little bit to see the arc `((55,0) -> (0,55))` example below:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("crystal").getContext('2d');
var frontback = new Path2D("M 10 10 h 100 v 100 h -100 Z");
var leftright = new Path2D("M 10 10 l 20 20 v 100 l -20 -20");

ctx.save();

ctx.stroke(frontback);
ctx.stroke(leftright);

ctx.translate(20,20);
ctx.stroke(frontback);
ctx.restore();

ctx.translate(100,0);
ctx.stroke(leftright);
ctx.restore();


var pos_ion = new Path2D("M 55 0 A 10 10 0 0 1 0 55");
ctx.stroke(pos_ion);
```

```html
<div><canvas id="crystal" /></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain the centering?  I'm trying to draw the circle in the center of the box, and as I play with the parameters I just can't figure out how to get it.  I tried moving to 45,55 and starting the circle at 65,55, and so on.  I drew the circle too far to the right.  I also tried using the `arc` method and it too drew everything too far to the right.  Using `restore`, `moveTo` and `restore` doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what the issue was.  I didn't realize that when you restore a saved context it not only brings up that context but also pops it off the stack.